# Wordpress - get all terms with the same name

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy-terms

Good morning.

Let's pretend that my "category" taxonomy includes several terms with the same name.
For example:

Kitchen
Furnitures > Kitchen
Tools > Kichen

I need a way to get the exact term to associate it programmatically to my posts.

I add that my client require that the post is associated only to the deepest level of the category structure ("kitchen", in my example).

Let's imagine this is the case: I need to retrieve data for Tools > Kitchen.

That's my idea (and my problem):

```
$found = get_term_by('name', 'Kitchen', 'category');
```

I hoped to get an array of all "Kitchen" terms so that I should be able to filter it by parent.
But I receive only the first term, because it was the first created on the DB.

Is there a solution?

Do I have to get all children of the parent with `get_term_children()` and then search for the correct one?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for `get_the_term_list()`.

- see @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/

> Retrieves a post’s terms as a list with specified format. Terms are linked to their respective term listing pages.

```
get_the_term_list( int $post_id, string $taxonomy, string $before = '', string $sep = '', string $after = '' )
```

In your case something like this should do the trick. If that's not enough, you could then filter out none related kitchen terms by checking if each term [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the `kitchen` string. Tho in that case, the use of a custom taxonomy might be a lot simpler.

```
<?php

echo strip_tags( get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'category', $before, ', ', $after) );
```

Comment: Unfortunately this not apply to my case.
At the end I decided to make a direct query via $wpdb. 

Thanks